# Polymorphism program

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I am needing help with polymorphism. I have no clue how to work with this. I have to write a program that creates an Orc and a Human and demonstrates the behavior of the classes. I am just needing some help with setting this program up. I have set up the classes with the information, but how do I get the createCharacter function to work? Would I have `characterTotal = characterStrength + characterDexterity + characterIntelligence` in the createCharacter function?  I know my program is not correct right now and I have some errors and things, but I am still just trying to get a better understanding of this.

**UPDATE:** 
I am having trouble with the createCharacter function. It is a pure virtual function and I am needing some help on how to get it to work.

For **Human** class **createCharacter** will:
 Get the values of STR, DEX and INT. Will calculate the total of the values.
 (Let’s assume STR = 17, DEX = 12 and INT = 10. It will store 37 into characterTotal.Itwill print out a message: “The strong human Paladin, has a total scoreof 37.” (Strong adjective comes due to STR being 17. If something is above 17 you should say something related. STR = strong, DEX = dexterous, INT =
 intelligent).

For **Orc** class **createCharacter** will:
 Get the values of STR, DEX and INT. Will calculate the total of the values.
 However Orcs receive -2 to INT and DEX. They receive +2 to STR. (Let’s
 assume STR = 16, DEX = 10 and INT = 8. It will store 16+2,10-2,8-2 = 28 into
 characterTotal.
 It will print out a message “The berserker Orc has a total score of 28.” (Here the
 Orcs get their adjectives from their clan names so you do not need to do
 something specific to STR, DEX or INT.)

CODE:

```
//character.h
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H

using namespace std;

class Character
{
    protected:
                float characterTotal;

    public:
                virtual void createCharacter() = 0; //Pure virtual function


};

#endif

//human.h
#ifndef HUMAN_H
#define HUMAN_H

#include "Character.h"
using namespace std;

class Human
{
    private:
                int characterStrength;
                int characterDexterity;
                int characterIntelligence;
                string characterType;

    public:
                Human();//Constructor 

                int getStength
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterStrength;

                    return characterStrength;
                }

                int getDexterity
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterDexterity;

                    return CharacterDexterity;
                }

                int getIntelligence
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterIntelligence;

                    return characterIntelligence;
                }

                string getType
                {
                    cout << "Please choose one of the following\n";
                    cout << "A -- Paladin \n";
                    cout << "B -- Ranger \n";
                    cout << "C -- Wizard \n";\
                    cin >> characterType;

                    return characterType;
                }


};

#endif

//orc.h
#ifndef ORC_H
#define ORC_H

#include "Character.h"
#include "Human.h"

using namespace std;

class orc
{
    private:
                int characterStrength;
                int characterDexterity;
                int characterIntelligence;
                string characterClan;

    public:
                orc(); //Constructor

                int getStrength
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number between 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterStrength;

                    return characterStrength;
                }

                int getDexterity
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number between 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterDexterity;

                    return characterDexterity;
                }

                int getIntelligence
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number between 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterIntelligence;

                    return characterIntelligence;
                }
                string getClan
                {
                    cout << "Please choose one of the following\n";
                    cout << "A -- Barbarian \n";
                    cout << "B -- Berserker \n";
                    cout << "C -- Vanguard \n";\
                    cin >> characterClan;

                    return characterClan;
                }

};
#endif
```

Comment: If `characterStrength` is possessed by all characters, you should put it in the character base class instead of repeating yourself.

Comment: Suggestion: start with the simplest possible program using polymorphism (and no user input), and understand that first, then apply what you've learnt to your assignment.  Any book or online tutorial should be able to walk you through the basics.  If you get stuck, it should at least be in a program with ~10 lines that's focused on the technical issues: posting that code and question's more likely to elicit help.

Comment: Please state a concrete question. Which problem/error are you encountering right now? P.S.: `int characterStrength();` (which looks like a function declaration) should be `int characterStrength;` (which would then be a private member variable).

Comment: Right now, I am just needing some help with the createCharacter function. I am not sure how to set it up. It is a pure virtual function, and I have read my book and looked online, but I don't quite understand what it is and the purpose of them.

Comment: To start working on `createCharacter`, you must add `void createCharacter() override { ... }` to your derived classes `Human` and `orc`, then inside the function body you can call the `getStrength()` etc. functions and print the required messages.

Answer (score 0):

Example: A class called `Account` posesses a container with `Character`. Your classes `Human` and `Orc` inherit both from `Character`. Inside of your `Human` class you may want to set spell `ABC` to all characters which are created (in `createCharacter`). But if the player creates an `Orc`, you might want to set another spell `XYZ` to it, instead of `ABC`. Base classes come in handy here. In this example you see one of these abstract functions in action (`Character::initCharacter`).
You can put in more abstract functions inside of `Character` **IF** the classes which are supposed to inherit from `Character` **MUST / NEED TO** implement these functions.

---

*This is only an example. If you want to do it properly, you need more than this and would have to modify all for database access and further abstraction.*

---

```
enum CharacterType
{
    CHAR_INVALID    = 0x0,
    CHAR_HUMAN      = 0x1,
    CHAR_ORC        = 0x4
};

class Character
{
public:
    Character(unsigned int charGUID) //You might want to set data in the constructor already
        : m_charGUID(charGUID)       //right after it has been load from Account::LoadAccountInformation()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor of \"Character\"" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Character(void) //Cleanup if needed
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of \"Character\"" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void createCharacter(void) = 0;
    virtual void initCharacter(void) = 0;

    CharacterType GetTypeID(void)
    { return m_typeID; }

protected:
    void SetTypeID(CharacterType ct)
    { m_typeID = ct; }

private:
    Character(const Character &);

    unsigned int m_charGUID;
    CharacterType m_typeID;
};

class Human : public Character
{
public:
    Human(unsigned int charGUID)
        : Character(charGUID)
    {
        SetTypeID(CHAR_HUMAN);
        std::cout << "Constructor of \"Human\"" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Human(void) //Cleanup if needed
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of \"Human\"" << std::endl;
    }

    void createCharacter(void) override
    {
        //Set data...
    }

    void initCharacter(void) override
    {
        std::cout << "You initialized a character of type \"Human\"" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Orc : public Character
{
public:
    Orc(unsigned int charGUID)
        : Character(charGUID)
    {
        SetTypeID(CHAR_ORC);
        std::cout << "Constructor of \"Orc\"" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Orc(void) //Cleanup if needed
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of \"Orc\"" << std::endl;
    }

    void createCharacter(void) override
    {
        //Set data...
    }

    void initCharacter(void) override
    {
        std::cout << "You initialized a character of type \"Orc\"" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Account
{
public:
    Account(unsigned int accountGUID)
    { m_accGUID = accountGUID; }

    //@Return: False if load from database failed
    bool LoadAccountInformation(void) //You could give it data also
    {
        //You could also load data directly from a database here if you'd like to
        //Here are just some sample values (partially hardcoded)

        characters.clear();
        const int charsOnAccount = 1; //Load from database
        for (int i = 0; i < charsOnAccount; ++i)
        {
            CharacterType ct = CHAR_HUMAN; //Load from database
            unsigned int characterGUID = i;
            switch (ct)
            {
                case CHAR_HUMAN:
                {
                    characters[characterGUID] = std::move(std::shared_ptr<Character>(new Human(characterGUID)));
                } break;
                case CHAR_ORC:
                {
                    characters[characterGUID] = std::move(std::shared_ptr<Character>(new Orc(characterGUID)));
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    std::cout << "Invalid character type: " << ct << std::endl; //Or log to file
                } break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void InitCharacters(void)
    {
        for (auto itr = std::begin(characters); itr != std::end(characters); ++itr)
            itr->second->initCharacter();
    }

private:
    //A unique account-GUID
    unsigned int m_accGUID;
    //Let's say a unique char-GUID and the Character object
    std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<Character> > characters;
    //And more information...
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Account ac = Account(1);
    ac.LoadAccountInformation();
    ac.InitCharacters();

    return 0;
}
```